# Is it idiomatic use of redux-saga to call a worker saga directly from a React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

I am using `redux-saga` having spent some time on core concepts of generators, generators with promises, and redux-saga itself. What I want below is to understand what is idiomatic and recommended, and what isn't.

In one file I define my root saga, watcher saga, and one worker saga (`fetchSupplierOrders`).

```
import {
    fetchSupplierOrders,
} from './supplierOrders';
import { takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* watchSupplierOrdersSagas() {
    yield takeLatest('REQUEST_FETCH_SUPPLIER_ORDERS', fetchSupplierOrders);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([watchSupplierOrdersSagas()]);
}
```

Here is the worker saga:

```
export function* fetchSupplierOrders() {
    try {
        const supplierOrders = yield call(getSupplierOrders);  // API call is in getSupplierOrders
        // normally here I would use redux-saga put to hit my redux reducers
        yield supplierOrders.map(({ id }) => id)
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: 'RECEIVE_ERROR_FETCH_SUPPLIER_ORDERS', error: error.message });
    }
}
```

I have a React component that when I click a button, it executes the worker saga. What I am trying to do here is to not go through the redux-saga watcher saga at all. I will simply execute the generator function myself in the component, and iterate through it. Usually, I would go through the watcher saga, and it would call a worker saga that would generate side effects by modifying redux state.

However, what if I want to make a network request, but I don't want to save the result in redux, but in local component state? I want the component to somehow get the results from the worker saga directly.

Here is the click handler for the button in the React component:

```
    const handleFetchSuppliers = event => {
        const it = fetchSupplierOrders({ payload: event.target.value });
        const res1 = await it.next().value;
        console.log('res1', res1);
        const res2 = it.next(res1);
        console.log('res2', res2);
```

This code will not work, because in the worker saga I am using `redux-saga`'s `call` function. If I remove the use of `call`, and call `getSupplierOrders` (an async function) directly, then the await works and all the correct values are console.logged.

Is it common to do this (executing a worker saga from a component to get the results of an API request)? But if I do it this way then I lose the benefit of using call (isn't this useful because it's easier to test?)

Before `redux-saga` I would simply dispatch a thunk using `redux-thunk`, which is basically using `async/await` all the way through.

Do people mix the use of `redux-thunk` and `redux-saga`? Is this frowned upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, what if I want to make a network request, but I don't want to save the result in redux, but in local component state?

If redux is not involved, then redux-saga is not the right tool to use. Just use the normal react approach: make the api request (often in componentDidMount), then wait for that promise to complete (with .then or await), then call setState.

If you want to have multiple ways to do the fetch (both via a saga, and via a direct call), then you could put the fetch into a helper function (regular function, not generator). The component and the saga could then both make use of the helper function, each wrapping it with whatever extra work they need to do.

For example:

```
// helper
async function fetchStuff() {
  const response = await fetch('some Url');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response.status;
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.map(({ id }) => id);
}

// In a saga...
function* watchFetch() {
  yield takeLatest('doFetch', fetchStuffSaga);
}

function* fetchStuffSaga() {
  try { 
    const data = yield call(fetchStuff);
    yield put({ type: 'success', payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: 'error', payload: err });
  } 
}

// In a component that dispatches an action:
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'doFetch' });
}


// In a component that doesn't want to dispatch an action:
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const data = await fetchStuff();
    this.setState({ data });
  } catch (err) {
    this.setState({ error: err });
  }
}
```

> This code will not work, because in the worker saga I am using redux-saga's call function. If I remove the use of call, and call getSupplierOrders (an async function) directly, then the await works and all the correct values are console.logged.

Sagas are not meant for manual iteration. If you try to manually iterate through a saga, you either need to have specialized knowledge about exactly what the saga will yield in what order, or you basically need to re-implement redux-saga yourself. The former is brittle and tightly coupled, the latter is a waste of effort.

> Is it common to do this (executing a worker saga from a component to get the results of an API request)?

No.

> Do people mix the use of redux-thunk and redux-saga? Is this frowned upon?

They're both trying to handle the same kinds of things (asynchronous actions). Your codebase will be simpler if you use just one approach, then trying to mix and match both.